# Python: In a DataFrame, how do I find the year that strings from one column appear in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe and want to loop through all strings within column c2 and print that string and the year it appears in column c2 and then also print the *first year* when it appears in column c1, if it exists in c1. And then tally the difference between the years in another column. **There are NaN values in c2.**

Example df:

```
id   year     c1                c2
0    1999     luke skywalker    han solo
1    2000     leia organa       r2d2
2    2001     han solo          finn
3    2002     r2d2              NaN
4    2004     finn              c3po
5    2002     finn              NaN
6    2005     c3po              NaN
```

Example printed result:

```
c2            year in c2   year in c1     delta
han solo      1999         2001           2
r2d2          2000         2002           2
finn          2001         2004           3
c3po          2004         2005           1
```

I'm using Jupyter notebook with python and pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in steps like this:

```
df1 = df[df.c2.notnull()].copy()

s = df.groupby('c1')['year'].first()
df1['year in c1'] = df1.c2.map(s)

df1 = df1.rename(columns={'year':'year in c2'})

df1['delta'] = df1['year in c1'] - df1['year in c2']

print(df1[['c2','year in c2','year in c1', 'delta']])
```

Output:

```
         c2  year in c2  year in c1  delta
0  han solo        1999        2001      2
1      r2d2        2000        2002      2
2      finn        2001        2004      3
4      c3po        2004        2005      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
df['year_c1'] = df['c2'].map(df.groupby('c1')['year'].agg('first'))\
                        .fillna(0).astype(int)

df = df.rename(columns={'year': 'year_c2'})
df['delta'] = df['year_c1'] - df['year_c2']

df = df.loc[df['c2'].notnull(), ['id', 'year_c2', 'year_c1', 'delta']]

#    id  year_c2  year_c1  delta
# 0   0     1999   2001.0      2
# 1   1     2000   2002.0      2
# 2   2     2001   2004.0      3
# 4   4     2004   2005.0      1
```

**Explanation**

- Map `c1` to `year`, aggregating by "first".
- Use this map on `c2` to calculate `year_c1`.
- Calculate `delta` as the difference between `year_c2` and `year_c1`.
- Remove rows with `null` in `c2` and order columns.